# how to capture the download time of a file in load test in jmeter

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

**I have a scenario where user logs in and downloads his CV and then logs out.
I want to know the download time of the file in jmeter**

Answer (score 0):

**Latency** is a difference between time when request was sent and time when response has started to be received.

Latency is a difference between time when request was sent and time when response has started to be received.

**Response time** (= Sample time = Load time = Elapsed time) is a difference between time when request was sent and time when response has been fully received. This you can find the the report generated by Listerners like "View Results in Tree" or preferred "**Simple Data Writer"**

So Response time always >= latency.

The larger file is, the larger difference between response time and latency will be (= Sample time = Load time = Elapsed time) is a difference between time when request was sent and time when response has been fully received.

So Response time always >= latency.

The larger file is, the larger difference between response time and latency will be

Answer (score 0):

Just change the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler label to match the action, i.e. if you have 3 HTTP Request samplers you can name them like:

1. `Log In`
2. `Download File`
3. `Log Out`

Once done you will see the metrics for each action in a [Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-2-listeners-aggregate-data-samples) (for example [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report))

[image: JMeter Aggregate Report]

or in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image: JMeter Reporting Dashboard]